# ADFS sharepoint 2013 "Page Not Found"

Tags: sharepoint-server, adfs

im trying to configure ADFS with sharepoint. 
ADFS-server is correctly configured and i can access ADFS Metadata

```
https://MyADFSMachine.2008r2.local/adfs/services/trust/mex
```

And

```
https://MyADFSMachine.2008r2.local/FederationMetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml
```

Then i toke the "Signin Certificate" from ADFS managment window to Sharepoint

[image]

I then created SPWebapplication on port 80 and Sitecollection with SSL.
the site collection is `https://intra.2008r2.local`
server and the run this powershell to configure ADFS with my sharepoint.
between SharePoint and ADFS server

```
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("C:\Certs\Intra SignIn Cert.cer")
New-SPTrustedRootAuthority -Name "ADFS Signing Certificate" -Certificate $cert


$EmailMap = New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "EmailAddress" -SameAsIncoming

$UPNMap = New-SPClaimTypeMapping -IncomingClaimType "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/upn" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "UPN" -SameAsIncoming

$realm = "urn:sharepoint:intra"

$signInURL="https://intra.2008r2.local"


$TrustedIdentity = New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer -Name "Crescent.com" -Description "ADFS Trusted users from Crescent.com Domain" -realm $realm -ImportTrustCertificate $cert -ClaimsMappings $EmailMap,$upnMap -SignInUrl $signInURL -IdentifierClaim $Emailmap.InputClaimType
```

when i try to access ADFS-metadata, i got "Page Not Found"

```
https://intra.2008r2.local/adfs/services/trust/mex
```

Access the Federation Metadata endpoint

```
https://Intra.2008r2.local/FederationMetadata/2007-
```

And im sure that the rules are correct on ADFS.

the new adfs login is configured on sharepoint, but when i select it i got redirected to loginpage again, and i can se in fiddler that the page cannot be found

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think `-SignInURL` should point to ADFS, not SharePoint site. On my box it's:

```
https://<adfsserver>/adfs/ls
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using SharePoint site for -SignInUrl attribute. It should be adfs server login url and not the SharePoint site url.